# iPython bad interpreter when run on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: ipython, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed iPython through pip (pip install ipython) and when I try to start the interactive shell it complains about the bad interpreter. I understand from other questions and answers that it somehow relates to the file endings of script files but I am not trying to run any certain script file so is this an issue of the ipython itself, pyenv-win or some other component and how could it be solved?

```
$ ipython
bash: /mnt/c/Users/myuser/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims/ipython: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```